# How to center everything inside navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center everything in bootstrap navbar, it's my code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I want to center div with class "container-fluid", I've tried adding "margin: 0 auto; float:none" to this div, but It doesn't work
I added this:

```
.container-fluid {
      margin: 0 auto !important;
      float: none !important;
    }
```

still doesn't work

Comment: Sometimes you have to add !important to override bootstrap styles. Ex. `margin: 0 auto !important;`. Try a few things and report back what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.navbar { display: flex; }`
(No need for the other CSS then)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEbrPz

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix that is to remove the class from first nav and div tags, then add center tag.

```html
<nav>
 <center>
  <div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </center>
</nav>
```

Comment: Those outer classes are essential in Bootstrap, and `<center>` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Or make wrapper with fixed width (if navbar doesnt change alot).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="wrap" style="
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 550px;
">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both `.navbar-header` and `.navbar-brand` are `float:left`, so you need to explicitly override that. Then you can center them by changing them to `display:inline-block` and  adding the `.text-center` class to their container.

```css
.navbar .text-center > * {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center"> <!-- added text-center class here -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```